# Why do some AAAA records behave strangely on existing A records?

Tags: ipv6, dns

I noticed the following odd behavior with AAAA records when querying existing A records. By base domains I mean domain names without subdomains. So when an A record exist and an AAAA record does not exist on specific records, I get a DNS response with "No errors" instead of getting the expected "Name error" flag.

Here are examples:

1. Querying a domain with IPv6 support:

   ```
   nslookup -type=aaaa cisco.com
   Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
   Address:  8.8.8.8

   Non-authoritative answer:
   Name:    cisco.com
   Address:  2001:420:1101:1::a
   ```
2. Querying a domain without IPv6 support:

   ```
   nslookup -type=aaaa microsoft.com
   Server: google-public-dns-a.google.com
   Address:  8.8.8.8

   Name:    microsoft.com
   ```

I would have expected:

```
nslookup -type=aaaa microsoft.com
Server: google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

*** google-public-dns-a.google.com can't find microsoft.com: Non-existent domain
```

Yet if I try a subdomain (example support.microsoft.com), the result will work for an A query, and the AAAA will return an empty result:

```
nslookup -type=a support.microsoft.com
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    e10315.g.akamaiedge.net
Address:  96.6.190.192
Aliases:  support.microsoft.com
          wildcard.support.microsoft.com.edgekey.net
```

AAAA:

```
nslookup -type=aaaa support.microsoft.com
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    support.microsoft.com
```

I would have expected:

```
nslookup -type=aaaa support.microsoft.com
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

*** google-public-dns-a.google.com can't find support.microsoft.com: Non-existent domain
```

Yet, when I query non-existing A & AAAA records, I get a proper answer on my AAAA queries... Is this by design or a DNS server bug? I wasn't able to find a reason for this behavior:

```
nslookup -type=aaaa dontexist.microsoft.com
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

*** google-public-dns-a.google.com can't find dontexist.microsoft.com: Non-existent domain
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actually found what I was looking for in [RFC4074](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4074):

> Suppose that an authoritative server has an A RR but has no AAAA RR
> for a host name.  Then, the server should return a response to a query
> for an AAAA RR of the name with the response code (RCODE) being  0
> (indicating no error) and with an empty answer section (see
> Sections 4.3.2 and 6.2.4 of [1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4074)). Such a response indicates that there
> is at least one RR of a different type than AAAA for the    queried
> name, and the stub resolver can then look for A RRs.

This explain exactly why we do not see "Record not found" for AAAA who have existing A records.